# Pig 10.0 - group the tuples and merge bags in a foreach

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'm using `Pig 10.0`.  I want to Merge bags in a foreach.  Let's say I have the following `visitors` alias:

```
(a, b, {1, 2, 3, 4}),
(a, d, {1, 3, 6}),
(a, e, {7}),
(z, b, {1, 2, 3})
```

I want to group the tuples on the first field and merge the bags with a set semantic to get the following following tuples:

```
({1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7}, a, 6) 
({1, 2, 3}, z, 3)
```

The first field is the union of the bags with a set semantic. The second field of the tuple is the group field. The third field is the number items in the bag.

I tried several variations around the following code (replaced SetUnion by Group/Distinct etc.) but always failed to achieve the wanted behavior:

```
DEFINE SetUnion        datafu.pig.bags.sets.SetUnion();

grouped = GROUP visitors by (FirstField);
merged = FOREACH grouped {
    VU = SetUnion(visitors.ThirdField);
    GENERATE 
        VU        as Vu,
        group     as FirstField,
        COUNT(VU) as Cnt;
    }
dump merged;
```

Can you explain where I'm wrong and how to implement the desired behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally managed to achieve the wanted behavior. A self contained example of my solution follows:

Data file:

```
a       b       1
a       b       2
a       b       3
a       b       4
a       d       1
a       b       3
a       b       6
a       e       7
z       b       1
z       b       2
z       b       3
```

Code:

```
-- Prepare data
in = LOAD 'data' USING PigStorage() 
        AS (One:chararray, Two:chararray, Id:long);

grp = GROUP in by (One, Two);
cnt = FOREACH grp {
        ids = DISTINCT in.Id;
        GENERATE
                ids        as Ids,
                group.One  as One,
                group.Two  as Two,
                COUNT(ids) as Count;
}       

-- Interesting code follows
grp2 = GROUP cnt by One;
cnt2 = FOREACH grp2 {
        ids = FOREACH cnt.Ids generate FLATTEN($0);
        GENERATE
                ids  as Ids,
                group      as One,
                COUNT(ids) as Count;
}               

describe cnt2;
dump grp2;
dump cnt2;
```

Describe:

```
Cnt: {Ids: {(Id: long)},One: chararray,Two: chararray,Count: long}
```

grp2:

```
(a,{({(1),(2),(3),(4),(6)},a,b,5),({(1)},a,d,1),({(7)},a,e,1)})
(z,{({(1),(2),(3)},z,b,3)})
```

cnt2:

```
({(1),(2),(3),(4),(6),(1),(7)},a,7)
({(1),(2),(3)},z,3)
```

Since the code uses a FOREACH nested in a FOREACH it requires Pig > 10.0.

I will let the question as unresolved for a few days since a cleaner solution probably exists.

Answer (score 0):

Found a simpler solution for this.

current_input = load '/idn/home/ksing143/tuple_related_data/tough_grouping.txt' USING PigStorage() AS (col1:chararray, col2:chararray, col3:int);

/* *But we do not need column 2. Hence eliminating to avoid confusion* */

relevant_input = foreach current_input generate col1, col3;

relevant_distinct = DISTINCT relevant_input;

relevant_grouped = group relevant_distinct by col1;

/* *This will give* */

(a,{(a,1),(a,2),(a,3),(a,4),(a,6),(a,7)})

(z,{(z,1),(z,2),(z,3)})

relevant_grouped_advance = foreach relevant_grouped generate (relevant_distinct.col3) as col3, group, COUNT(relevant_distinct.col3) as count_val;

/* This will give desired result */

({(1),(2),(3),(4),(6),(7)},a,6)

({(1),(2),(3)},z,3)