# PIG how to merge two groups?

Tags: python, apache-pig

What I have

```
{a, {(1,2),(3,4)}, {(5,6),(7,8)}}
```

What I want is

```
{a, {(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(7,8)}}
```

I was going through PIG manual but did not find any way of appending two BAGs together.

Ofcourse final solution would be to use some python PDF, but is there a PIG provided way to do it ?

Comment: Maybe this will get you where you want to go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15660920/pig-10-0-group-the-tuples-and-merge-bags-in-a-foreach

Comment: thanks @WinnieNicklaus  But that code is so eecky :|

I would rather prefer python. :)

Comment: I agree. There is no built-in functionality but the UDF would be trivial to write.

Comment: def join(bag1,bag2):

  for tuple in bag2:

      bag1.append(tuple)

  return bag1;

I think.

Comment: @Ajeet Assuming the schema for the tuples in the bag are the same, you could just do `def join(BAG1, BAG2): return BAG1 + BAG2`.  I can't remember if bags are passed as tuples or lists, but if they are passed as tuples you just have to change the return to `return list(BAG1) + list(BAG2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no builtin function that does this.  However, you should be able to do this in pure pig latin, but it is going to be much slower than a UDF of any kind.  You'll have to use `FLATTEN` and `UNION` like this:

```
-- A: {key: chararray, vals1: {(one:int, two:int)}, vals2: {(one:int, two:int)}}

B = FOREACH A GENERATE key, FLATTEN(vals1) ;
C = FOREACH A GENERATE key, FLATTEN(vals2) ;

D = UNION B, C ;

-- Group and filter out 'key' from the result bag.
E = FOREACH (GROUP D BY key)
    GENERATE group As key, D.(one, two) AS joined_bag ;
```

Notice how much uglier this is than a simple python UDF written like:

```
# Make sure to include the appropriate ouputSchema
def join_bags(BAG1, BAG2):
    return BAG1 + BAG2
```

And used like:

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE key, pythonUDFs.join_bags(vals1, vals2) ;
```

This would be much simpler if `UNION` was allowed in nested `FOREACH`s, but sadly it is not.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [BagConcat](http://datafu.incubator.apache.org/docs/datafu/1.2.0/datafu/pig/bags/BagConcat.html) UDF from [DataFu](http://datafu.org).   It does exactly what you want.

Example from the documentation:

```
define BagConcat datafu.pig.bags.BagConcat();
-- This example illustrates the use on a tuple of bags

-- input:
-- ({(1),(2),(3)},{(3),(4),(5)})
-- ({(20),(25)},{(40),(50)})
input = LOAD 'input' AS (A: bag{T: tuple(v:INT)}, B: bag{T: tuple(v:INT)});

-- output:
-- ({(1),(2),(3),(3),(4),(5)})
-- ({(20),(25),(40),(50)})
output = FOREACH input GENERATE BagConcat(A,B);
```